# Need to convert netcdf fill values from Matlab to R

Tags: r, matlab, netcdf

I have this piece of code in Matlab which I believe is replacing netcdf fill values with Matlab fill values.
How do I convert this code into R ? I am using netcdf4

```
inp.COAST_RLON.data ( inp.COAST_RLON.data< -900 ) = NaN;
inp.COAST_RLAT.data ( inp.COAST_RLAT.data< -900 ) = NaN;
```

Comment: Use `[`, `]` and `NA`, no? Instead of `(`, `)` and `NaN`.

Comment: `inp.COAST_RLON.data[inp.COAST_RLON.data < -900] = NA`

Comment: This gives you the longitudes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an R vector, matrix, or array and wish to replace values matching a criterion with another value, you do:

```
 foo[criterion]=replacement
```

So your criterion is `foo < -900` and your replacement is `NA`.

So whatever you read from `netcdf` files as vectors, matrices, or arrays can be fixed:

```
 rlon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"COAST_RLON")
 rlon[rlon < -900] = NA
```

I'm not totally familiar with what `ncvar_get` returns but I think its a vector, matrix, or array.